# How to wait child process with QProcess?

Tags: c++, qt, multiprocessing, qt5, qprocess

I am try to wait child process with this code:

```
auto child = new QProcess;
child->start("cmd.exe");
child->waitForFinished();
```

But cmd.exe doesn't open and the main program runs. What is the error?

And how I should wait correctly? `waitForFinished` waits 30000 msecs by default. What if I want to wait infinitely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest checking the return value to see if the program is started successfully using the `waitForStarted` ([doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#waitForStarted)) and try to use the full path of CMD: `"C:/windows/system32/cmd.exe"`.

Also, check online, the question is already been asked [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/40962/qprocess-start-doesn-t-display-a-console-window-for-console-programs-windows/6).

To wait infinitely you need to call `waitForFinished` with -1 ([doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#waitForFinished)):

```
child->waitForFinished(-1);
```